# rails sorcery gem and ldap authentication using net-ldap and/or activeldap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ldap

I have a rails 3.1.1 app which is using sorcery gem for the authentication. I was wondering if I can hook in LDAP in there so that I can authenticate against an ldap server instead of a database table. Has anyone implemented this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done it with devise and devise-ldap auth.
Here are some of the links I found in my search.

https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable

http://corrupt.net/2010/07/05/LDAP-Authentication-With-Devise/

Comment: Ok, but how does this help to authenticate with Sorcery?  Does the "devise_ldap_authenticatable" gem work with Sorcery?  I have Sorcery hooks throughout an  app - creating users, changing passwords, etc.  Would all that need to be replaced with Devise-compatible code?